# Keystore not working on unity 2017.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, publish, keystore, sign

our team started to work on an old project to fix bugs and add new features. But we have a problem on the keystore file. After project updated to Unity 2017 we started to get an error that says:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to sign APK package.
/Users/work/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/apksigner sign --ks 

"/Users/work/Desktop/work game/MAIN/game.keystore" --ks-pass 
pass:"***" --ks-key-alias "***" --key-pass pass:"***" "/Users/work/Desktop/work/game/MAIN/Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"

 stderr[
Failed to load signer "signer #1"
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:606)
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:390)
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:331)
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:344)
at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1953)
at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadKeyStoreFromFile(ApkSignerTool.java:829)
at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromKeyStore(ApkSignerTool.java:719)
at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(ApkSignerTool.java:659)
at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.access$500(ApkSignerTool.java:611)
at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:266)
at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:89)
]
stdout[



]
exit code: 2
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildAPK.SignPackage (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildAPK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Tried with different JDK versions. Changed keystore name, its destination but still same result. The same keystore works on Unity 5.6 perfectly. The update should be published soon. Solving the problem as soon as possible is crucial for us.

Answer (score 0):

Under Publishing Settings, try changing the Build System to Gradle (New) instead of Internal (Default).
If above not work try  updating Android Studio and also update the android SDK.
If above not working try below steps

1) just open https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

2) scroll down to the bottom of that page

3) go to downloads

4) scroll down to the bottom of that page

5) find Windows "tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip" download and unzip it

5) find MacOSX "tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip" download and unzip it.

6) In the SDK path replace the tools folder.

Original source [link](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-build-fails-when-the-latest-android-sdk-tools-25-dot-3-1-version-is-used)

Comment: We think that problem caused by unity 2017. Back to unity 5.6 until it gets fixed. But still looking for solutions.

Comment: Gonna try it soon. Ty